# Kendo treeview select a checkbox having problems

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo treeview with checkboxes

checkbox 1 is ABC
checkbox 2 is CED
checkbox 3 is DEF

I want to check only checkbox 2 the below code does not work

```
 $("input:checkbox[Name=CED]", "#Treeview").prop("checked", true);
```

also i see this code to get all values

```
function gatherSelectedNames(treeViewId) {
    var checkedNodes = [];
    var treeview = $("#" + treeViewId).data("kendoTreeView");
    var nodes = treeview.dataSource.view();



    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {


        if (nodes[i].checked) {
            checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].Name);
        }

        if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
            gatherSelectedIds(nodes[i].children.view());
        }
    }
    return checkedNodes
}
```

I tried this also

```
if (nodes[i].Name == "CED")
{
nodes[i].checked = true; 
}
```

does not work .